# How to change into different sections of your application easily

Tags: c#, wpf, application-design, architecture

Im currently trying to create an application that will require 10+ different "pages" with different content and controls, and i need to switch back and forth between them on particular events.

What ive been doing, is just creating all the different sections in grids, and setting their visibility to collapsed, and then when i need to show them, just switch out the visible grid to the new one.

This has several drawbacks, im assuming its very poor from a coding standpoint, and this pretty much dis-allows me from using the designer at all. (i have no idea what performance implications it has, either)

on top of that, every time i switch to the new page, i need to reset all the components (textbox's etc) to their default states, as they dont get reset by becoming invisible :P

on to my question: i need a way to map out all the different pages, provide visually attractive transitions between them, and be able to use a designer to create them (and i dont mean designing it somewhere and then just copying the xaml)

I had looked around, and ran into SketchFlow and it seemed like the perfect solution, i could fade between pages and map everything on a flow chart easily, and then i realized it was only for app prototypes and i couldnt actually compile it as a normal application... and i needed to inherit from a custom Window class aswell.

is there something out there that allows me to do this? or how can i code this to work properly?

note: this ABSOLUTELY needs to stay within one window. i cant venture out into having 10+ different windows that pop up every time i need to change to something. as this happens very frequently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the separate sections in individual user controls. This would allow you to design each of them easily. Then on your form use code to create and load a new instance of particular user control that represents the section you need to show, and when transitioning, load the new section and unload the current. this would allow your form to stay relatively lightweight.

An alternative is to create a navigation application and split your sections into separate XAML view and use the standard navigation service to switch between them.

WPF [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx)
[Creating Navigation Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/cc514215) video tutorial

Comment: i like your user control idea, i will probably look into that, but what is this navigation application thing you are talking about? care to go into more details, or provide reference links?

Comment: Added some links to the answer to get you started on Navigation applications

Comment: looks like navigation applications is not what i was looking for.. but thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna convert your "Pages" to usercontrols and use some transitions like mentioned in the below link to switch between controls

http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=280

for more on using transitions look here

http://www.japf.fr/2009/04/adding-transitions-to-a-mvvm-based-dialog/
or

http://www.japf.fr/2008/07/8/comment-page-1/